# Updating Nginx block to do two things that aren't working

Tags: nginx, server

For Nginx, I'm attempting to do two things:

1. Redirect anyone who comes in to the site from www to non-www.
2. The server defaults to error 500 instead of 404 when the URL path doesn't exist.

This is my current configuration of my server:

```
server {
        root /var/www/project/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # manag$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I attempted adding a forward for any www traffic to move into non-www but that didn't do anything (I think because of certbot). Also I tried to update the URL for returning 404 instead of 500, but what it did was it made anything outside of the homepage a 404. So I reset it to what you see above.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Redirect anyone who comes in to the site from www to non-www.

The cleanest solution is to define a separate `server` block only for this purpose:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    return       301 http://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

You can verify that it works by putting

```
127.0.0.1 localhost example.com www.example.com
```

in your computer's hosts file.

```
$ curl -I http://www.example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 27 Aug 2021 06:14:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://example.com/
```

> 2. The server defaults to error 500 instead of 404 when the URL path doesn't exist.

The 500 HTTP status code is probably caused by your `index.php` script.

Comment: This didn't reroute the user from www to non www

Comment: It should work, I actually tested it (see my edited answer). If it's not working for you then you most likely have some sort of other issue. Note also that you have to configure two blocks if using both HTTP and HTTPS.